# undefined method to_h for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, enums

```
User.all.group('users.gender').count.map { |k, v| [User.genders.key(k), v] }.to_h
```

it gives an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for [["Male", 44], ["Female", 2]]:Array
```

It works fine on localhost but on heroku it give errir

Comment: The `to_h` method is only available in `Ruby version 2.1` or higher. your heroku version is lower than 2.1 so giving error

Comment: any another method like to_h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can try using `reduce` method in this way

```
User.all.group('users.gender').count.map { |k, v| {User.genders.key(k) => v} }.reduce({}, :merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

Old way to convert array to hash for Ruby < 2.1

```
Hash[*array.flatten]
...
arr = [["Male", 44], ["Female", 2]]
Hash[*arr.flatten]
=> {"Male"=>44, "Female"=>2}
```

In your case

```
Hash[*(User.all.group('users.gender').count.map{ |k, v| [User.genders.key(k), v] })]
```